# Use a string captured from regex to format a datetime

Tags: regex, powershell, datetime, formatting, datetime-format

What i'd like to do is use powershell to parse a file and replace certain keywords in the file with values. This is working but im having a problem formatting a datetime using a captured regex group.
The file im parsing contains the following text:

> $DATETIME$
>   $DATETIME=yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz$
>   $DATETIME=yyyy$

I have a powershell script that extracts the keyword DATETIME and captures the supplied format. Whenever I try to use the captured format it fails because (I suspect) the captured string variable $1 is used as the format string and not value of $1.

```
Get-Content $inputfile) `
    -replace '\$DATETIME[=]?(.*)\$', $(Get-Date -Format '$1') `
| Set-Content $outputfile
```

If anyone can help i'd appreciate it.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the match value into a callback method, or use it like

```
PS> $s = '$DATETIME=yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz$'
PS> [regex]::Replace($s,'\$DATETIME=?([^$]*)\$', {param($match) $(Get-Date -Format $match.Groups[1].Value) })
DATETI6E=2018-06-29T15:09:30+02:00
```

The `'$1'` in your original solution is passed to `Get-Date` as a literal `$1` string and is thus not working as expected. These replacement backreferences can only be used in string replacement patterns, but cannot be used when the match needs further manipulations.

Note that I slightly modified the pattern to match:

- `\$` - a `$` char
- `DATETIME` - a literal substring
- `=?` - 1 or 0 `=` chars
- `([^$]*)` - Group 1 (the value captured here will be used to generate the datetime string): any 0+ chars other than `$` (if there are more than 1 matches on a single line, it will still work and it will match faster than a greedy (or even lazy) dot pattern)
- `\$` - a `$` char

Comment: should use `$match.Groups[1]` instead of `$match.value`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul True, sorry, fixed.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Works like a charm! Is there a way to make this work with the '-replace' method?

Comment: @Reznoir No, there is no way since it expects a string replacement pattern only.